# Не могу сформулировать SQL запрос правильно, PDO

Tags: php, sql

Нужно найти одну запись в двух таблицах с разной структурой но с одинаковым именем поля, пробую так:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM category_tree DESC)'.
        'UNION'.
        '(SELECT * FROM pages) WHERE url = :url';
```

В каждой таблице есть поле 'url'

Comment: Нельзя объединять таблицы с разной структурой.
Каким вы видите результат?

Comment: Если URL используется как уникальный ключ, то почему никто не предложил обычный LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Конструкция `WHERE` в SQL применима к конкретному `SELECT`, для всего `UNION` задать `WHERE` нельзя.

Кроме того вы указываете, что структура таблиц отличается, а `UNION` требует что бы все подзапросы возвращали одинаковое количество колонок с одинаковыми типами данных. Поэтому использовать `*` в списке выборки недопустимо, необходимо перечислять явно те колонки, которые должен вернуть каждый из подзапросов и их количество/типы должны совпадать.

Таким образом ваш запрос должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
  SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM category_tree
   WHERE url = :url
  UNION
  SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM pages
   WHERE url = :url
```

В принципе можно конечно `UNION` из двух таблиц без условий выборки заключить в скобки и сделать внешний `SELECT` для которых он будет в `FROM`, но данный вариант я не привожу, т.к. делать так категорически не рекомендуется в виду того, что оптимизатор запросов в этом случае не сможет правильно применить индексы, даже если они есть, применит соединение всех таблиц во временную и время выполнения запроса и нагрузка на сервер будет очень большой.

Answer (score 1):

Если же у вас есть ещё и другие одинаковые столбцы в таблицах, и вы хотите их различать в ответе:

```
SELECT category_tree.*,pages.* FROM category_tree, pages WHERE category_tree.url = pages.url
```

Comment: Спасибо даже не думал что так быстро ответите, но решил не делать такой длинный запрос а разбил на 2 метода MVC

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM category_tree, pages WHERE category_tree.url = pages.url
```

Comment: Всем спасибо за отзывчивость